# Django Rest Framework - response.set_cookie() not setting cookie in browser but working in postman and in browsable api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, setcookie, django-cors-headers, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am struggling with setting jwt token in httponly cookie. I tried many solution but not working. I am working with localhost "127.0.0.1" but when I try to login the cookies sent by server not display in my frontend working at "127.0.0.1:5501" but if I try with Browsable api working at "127.0.0.1:8000" it works fine and I can check my cookies easily.

***I noticed a weird thing too. If I login via my frontend "127.0.0.1:5501", cookies not set but if I try with browsable api working at "127.0.0.1:8000" and then switch to my "127.0.0.1:5501" tab I can see that cookies their too. This a very Weird thing and I don't know the reason behind this.***

**Please help me to resolve this issue.**

Views.py

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self,request,format=None):
    
        data = request.data
        
        response = Response()
        username = data.get('username', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                data = get_tokens_for_user(user)
                response.set_cookie(
                                    key = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE'], 
                                    value = data["access"],
                                    expires = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME'],
                                    secure = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE'],
                                    httponly = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY'],
                                    samesite = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE']
                                        )
                csrf.get_token(request)
                response.data = {"Success" : "Login successfully","data":data}
                
                return response
            else:
                return Response({"No active" : "This account is not active!!"},status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        else:
            return Response({"Invalid" : "Invalid username or password!!"},status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Fetch Api request

```
async function login(email,password)
{
    
    let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/account/login/',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            
        },
        withCredentials: true,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'username': email,
            'password': password
        })

    

    })
    return response;
}
```

Settings.py file

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = default_headers + (
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
)

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:5501",
]


# ////////////////custom settings/////////////source : stackoverflow/////////////////////
    'AUTH_COOKIE': 'access_token',  # Cookie name. Enables cookies if value is set.
    'AUTH_COOKIE_DOMAIN': None,     # A string like "example.com", or None for standard domain cookie.
    'AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE': False,    # Whether the auth cookies should be secure (https:// only).
    'AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY' : True, # Http only cookie flag.It's not fetch by javascript.
    'AUTH_COOKIE_PATH': '/',        # The path of the auth cookie.
    'AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE': 'Lax',  # Whether to set the flag restricting cookie leaks on cross-site requests.
                                # This can be 'Lax', 'Strict', or None to disable the flag.
```

Postman demo
[image]

Browsable api demo

[image]

Frontend demo
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are also struggling with this issue. Just make sure that you have above setting and follow this simple update.

```
let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/account/login/',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'username': email,
            'password': password
        })

    

    })
```

It should be **credentials** only.